# Looping in SSRS Report Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Recently, im come across the situation where i've to loop through each rows in the Tablix Like :

```
Foreach(rows in Tablix)
{
    //Operation
}
```

But i dont think its possible.

So, is it Possible to Loop through the Rows inside Tablix?

My Problem Which made me do that is :

I've an tablix where a Column contains the : First(Rs!Field) inside the Row Group
And, In the last Row outside the Group i want to Sum(First(Rs!Field)), mean, 
I want to Sum,  First Only Field from the each Row Group.
But its not possible with SSRS. I even cant sum up the Sum(Reportitems!textBox.value) inside the Tablix.

Thats why i come accorss that situation.

I know there is no Solution for the Above, that why, I was thinking about if there is any Looping Statement Available.

I'd even tried the Function Code to Set and Get the Values Like :

```
Public Shared Dim Total as Double
Public Function SetTotal(ByRef val)
{
    Total=Total+val
}

Public function GetTotal()as Double
{
    return Total
}
```

But, this way, If i Scroll to the Pages Forth and Back, each time it sum up the values to the existing.

Hope you understand. I've tried everything possible i think.

So, please let me know, if there i can achieve any looping Functionalities?

Thank You in advance.

I've added the Pictures :

[image: Problem]

[image: Tried This Too]

Comment: Thanks for all the detail... Is it also possible to add a simple dataset with the minimum amount of data to show an example of the data you're using and your specific requirements for this data?

Comment: Also, this is tagged SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2008R2... Can you please confirm exactly which version this applies to?

Comment: It is SSRS2008-R2. No i dont think so. Im not authorized to modify the stored Procedures.\

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I didn't mean you need to update the underlying stored procedure, but can you update the question with some sample data that we can test against? Basically, five or so rows of data with the relevant columns, plus the required end result, so that we can use this data to replicate your issue.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much @Ian. I've solved the issue by actually modifying the stored Procedure with the management authority. What i have done is, Stored procedure it self fetch the Distinct Sum of the group data, and In SSRS i maintained to show only First Record.

Comment: However, i still to wish to know that, if it is possible to Loop Through the Rows inside the Tablix. Once again Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it; I was thinking you could resolve this using an aggregate of an aggregate at the report level. IMO there's no real useful way of looping through rows, the link at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx is probably the best example you'll find, but you can see it's pretty flaky.